# Windows 7 not connecting to network when rebooting

Tags: windows-7, networking

Every time I reboot my Windows 7 (Home Premium) machine, I have to "fix" the connection before it will connect to anything.

How can I set it so that it connects automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Do you mean the built-in Repair feature?

Comment: Yes.  It looks like it's getting a DHCP assignment, but if I do it from the command prompt using ipconfig /renew, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this before.  I uninstalled  the network card from the device manager and rebooted.  I then let Windows rediscover the device and it worked perfectly from that point.